# SqlCommand not adding data

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I want to add data in my database it is not working; however, I can see the data in the data grid (my project is a windows forms project)

My code :

```
string query = @"insert into produits
                    (ref_pdt, designation_pdt, quantite_pdt, prix_pdt)
                 values ('"+ tb_ref_add.Text + "','" + tb_des_add.Text + "','" + 
                    tb_qte_add.Text + "','" + tb_prix_add.Text + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, loaddatabaseconnexion.connexion_BDD());
    SqlDataReader DataReader;
    try
    {
        DataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show("Données sauvegardées !");
        formulaire_principal.tableau();
    }
    catch (Exception es)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
    }
```

Sorry for the mistakes I’m French ;)

Comment: You have many problems with that little snippet.  First, that hasnt been the correct way to create SQL for many years.  Study how to use SQL Parameters always.  A DataReader is a sub optimal choice to INSERT data (its a **reader**!); then you never execute anything.

Comment: You definitely need to fix that string concatenation. SQL injection is not your friend, and there's never a good reason to use properly parametrised code.

Comment: If you can step through this in the debugger without error, double check your connection string.  You may not be inserting into the database you think you are.

Comment: Try `ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of `ExecuteReader()` and use a parameterized query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @NoneOfTheAbove already said, there are many problems here. One that was not mentioned is that you are trying to add a quantity and a price as text enclosed in quotes.
I assume that the two columns `quantite_pdt` (quantity) and `prix_pdt` (price) are of a numeric type in the table. But you can circumvent this problem by using command parameters.
They automatically take care of the right formatting. This is especially valuable for `DateTime` values, but also for `string` values as they can contain quotes that would have to be escaped otherwise.

In the following example I assume the first two columns are text columns, that the quantity is an `int` and the price is a `decimal`. You must pass the command parameters by using values of a type compatible to the corresponding column type in the table. (In real life code you would probably want to use `Int32.TryParse` and `Decimal.TryParse` and do appropriate error handling.) And do not forget to adapt the `SqlDbType` and the conversions used in this example to your real column types.

```
string query = @"insert into produits
                (ref_pdt, designation_pdt, quantite_pdt, prix_pdt)
                values (@refp, @desig, @quant, @prix)";
try {
    using (var conn = loaddatabaseconnexion.connexion_BDD())
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn)) {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@refp", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tb_ref_add.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@desig", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tb_des_add.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@quant", SqlDbType.Int).Value =
            Int32.Parse(tb_qte_add.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@prix", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value =
            Decimal.Parse(tb_qte_add.Text);

        conn.Open();
        int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (rowsAffected == 0) {
            MessageBox.Show("Il y a eu un problème !"); // There was a problem!
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("Données sauvegardées !"); // Data saved!
            formulaire_principal.tableau();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I also assume that `loaddatabaseconnexion.connexion_BDD()` creates a new connection at each call. This is important, as the `using` statement automatically closes and disposes the connection at the end.

As you can see, I am using `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` to execute the command, as no records are returned. This method tells you how many records were affected by the command.

See also (in French): [.Net, SQL Server, et les requêtes paramétrées (C#)](https://webman.developpez.com/articles/aspnet/sqlparameter/csharp/)

Comment: Do not use [addwithvalue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @SMor- why not? That’s what it is for.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you have to revisit your approach to avoid [sql injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You better try some ORM like Entity Framework, or at least use stored procedures.

However, if you have to maintain this code for some reason, you need to use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `ExecuteReader` [check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.7.2)

The below code shall hit the database and either work or throw exception if you have issues with data types or string concatenation

```
    string query = @"insert into produits
                    (ref_pdt, designation_pdt, quantite_pdt, prix_pdt)
                 values ('"+ tb_ref_add.Text + "','" + tb_des_add.Text + "','" + 
                    tb_qte_add.Text + "','" + tb_prix_add.Text + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, loaddatabaseconnexion.connexion_BDD());
    SqlDataReader DataReader;
    try
    {
        //I assume you have already opened the connection as you didn't mention any exceptions in your question 
        cmd.ExcuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Données sauvegardées !");
        formulaire_principal.tableau();
    }
    catch (Exception es)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
    }
```

**Hint:**

You better log the string `query` or add a watch on it in the debug mode and try to run it directly from SSMS to make sure it is concatenated properly